# What does these square brackets in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc

I read the code below in [Indexed Monad](http://fumieval.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/05/04/144840)

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Control.Monad.Indexed.State
import Control.Monad.Indexed
import Language.Haskell.IndexedDo

hoge :: IxState Int [Int] ()
hoge = [ido|do
    imodify (*10)
    imodify show
    imodify reverse
    imodify (++"123")
    imodify $ map fromEnum
    |]
```

What is the syntax of these symbols `[|....|]` ?

Is it some kind of syntax sugar ?

Comment: This is [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [quasiquotation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html#th-quasiquotation) syntax. See also the [wiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation). The text between `[ido|` and `|]` is passed verbatim to the quasiquoter `ido`, which uses it to generate some Haskell code at compile-time.